# Update GRAVATAR in mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'abc', '123');
    mysql_select_db('foo');
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT gravtar_c FROM users'); // 10 rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $email = $row['gravtar_c'];
    }
    $size = 45;
    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?s=" . $size;
    echo ($grav_url);
    $rest = substr($grav_url, -37, -5);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $result = mysql_query('UPDATE users SET grav_hash_c = "'.$rest.'"');
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It updates with default values for all rows. I need it to select `gravtar_c` (which are different email addresses) from each row and then update each row in column `grav_hash_c` based on hash value (`$rest`).

Effectively loop through select and update.

Comment: can use a single mysql update statement for this purpose instead of looping numerous unnecessary update statements

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement so it just updates the row you want.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all that with a single SQL query:

```
UPDATE users SET grav_hash_c=MD5(LOWER(TRIM(gravtar_c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $email = $row['gravtar_c'];
    $size = 45;
    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?s=" . $size;
    echo ($grav_url);
    $rest = substr($grav_url, -37, -5);
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET grav_hash_c = '".$rest."' where gravtar_c = '".$email."' ");
}
```

Use `where` condition in update query. as well as do all stuff within while because out of while loop your `$email` variable replaced with last value of `$row['gravtar_c']`

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in